# Which models of iPhone 5 are compatible with CDMA in India?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers, cdma

Can I use my CDMA sim in iPhone 5 ? I am using TATA INDICOM CDMA sim.

Answer (score 1):

No.

iPhones only have GSM SIM slots.

The CDMA iPhone 5 can only use CDMA on the carrier which sold the phone. Those phones also have a GSM nanoSIM slot for use around the world.

Answer (score 0):

The Sprint iPhone 5 is CDMA and has a slot. And it uses a CDMA SIM card. Plus it supports GSM too. Therefore it does work.

Source: Personal experience.

Comment: Answers are reordered in StackExchange, so you can not say "false" in an answer as a comment to another one.